# How do I omit .virtualenv packages when testing Django project with Coverage.py

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, virtualenv

I have a Django project which I want to test with Coverage.py. I want to exclude the files in `.virtualenvs`.
I am using pipenv and the editor is VS Code. Coverage version is 5.5

I followed the documentation instructions to create a `.coveragec` file in the root directory of the project. I then ran the test but Coverage does not omit the packages in `.virtualenvs`.

**.coveragec**

```
[run]
source = .
omit = *.virtualenvs/*,*tests*,*apps.py*,*manage.py*,*__init__.py*,*migrations*,*asgi*,*wsgi*,*admin.py*,*urls.py*

[report]
omit = *.virtualenvs/*,*tests*,*apps.py*,*manage.py*,*__init__.py*,*migrations*,*asgi*,*wsgi*,*admin.py*,*urls.py*
```

When this approach did not work, I then resorted to using the Command line approach. This did not also work.

**cmd commands**

```
coverage run --omit=*./virtualenvs/*,*tests*,*apps.py*,*manage.py*,*__init__.py*,*migrations*,*asgi*,*wsgi*,*admin.py*,*urls.py* manage.py test -v 2

coverage html --omit=*./virtualenvs/*,*tests*,*apps.py*,*manage.py*,*__init__.py*,*migrations*,*asgi*,*wsgi*,*admin.py*,*urls.py*
```

I have also used `.venv` instead of `.virtualenvs` but it still does not work.
What can I do?

Comment: Could you share your project directory structure? You can take a screenshot of the appearance of directories from your IDE

Comment: `coveragec` should be `coveragerc`

Comment: Thanks @BrianD, that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Just as @BrianD said, I solved it by renaming the file `.coveragec` to `.coveragerc`